# zedgraph's point is not clear

Tags: c#

I am using zedGraph and trying to develop the sensor control application. but while I run the program my graph is not clear. And z1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear() code is not working
My program is below :

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
                while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                DatafromCOM = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                double iData;
                var ok = double.TryParse(txtKQ.Text, out iData);
                if (DatafromCOM.Trim() != "Water Level" && ok)
                {

                        i = (i + 1) % 100;
                        x[i] = (double)iData;
                        y[i] = iData;
                        listPointsOne.Add(i, iData);
                        z1.GraphPane.AddCurve(null, x, y, Color.Red, SymbolType.Circle);
                        z1.GraphPane.AddCurve(null, listPointsOne, Color.Blue, SymbolType.VDash);
                        z1.AxisChange();
                        z1.Invalidate();
                        z1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
                   }  
               }
         }
```

Comment: What is he content of `txtKQ.Text`? Are you sure that can convert to a double without error? HAving said that, we don't know which line of code is causing the problem, what debgging have you tried so far?

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code? Which line exactly is raising the exception? And *btw, this other code isn't working either* belongs in a separate question on its own. Please spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: niksan, you should Google your problem before you ask a question. But see if you can work out the problem from [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nTJafI). Why do test1 and test2 pass but test3 fails?

Comment: @DavidG in  double iData = Convert.ToDouble(txtKQ.Text); line is problem and txtKQ.Text is text area for sensor data output

Comment: @niksan so what happens if `txtKQ.Text` is empty or contains a value that can't be parsed as a double? Clue: you made a question about it.

Comment: @john its solved but my graph is not clear with  z1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear(); do you have any idea with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest changing this

```
if (DatafromCOM.Trim() != "Water Level")
{
    double iData = Convert.ToDouble(txtKQ.Text); 
    x[i] = (double)iData; 
    //Etc...
```

to this

```
double iData;
var ok = double.TryParse(txtKQ.Text, out iData);
if (DatafromCOM.Trim() != "Water Level" && ok)
{
    x[i] = iData; 
    //Etc...
```